# Virtualbox can connect to network but not when using vpn

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have a virtualbox running ubuntu on a Windows Host. I am over a wireless connection, when I start it up without being connected to my work VPN I can connect to the internet. When I start it up after connecting to the VPN I cannot connect to the internet.

I use bridged networking and give the vpn as my network name.

Comment: Are you sure your works VPN is set up for internet access?